# How to call HtmlHelper method in partial view using MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to Mvc4.Basically I wnat to create dynamic tabs having menus and submenus.

Here is My Htmlhelper class:

```
namespace DBMvc.Htmlhlpr
{
public static class HtmlHelperExtension
{
    public static String ParentMenus(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<menu> Menu)
    {
        string htmlOutput = string.Empty;
        if (Menu.Count() > 0)
        {
            htmlOutput += "<ul class='sf-menu'>";
            var Mainmenu = from mainMenu in Menu where mainMenu.Catid == null select mainMenu;
            foreach (menu m in Mainmenu)
            {
                htmlOutput += "<li>";
                htmlOutput += LinkExtensions.ActionLink(html, m.Depname, null);
                htmlOutput += SubMenus(html, Menu, m.Depid);
                htmlOutput += "</li>";

            }
            htmlOutput += "</ul>";
        }
        return htmlOutput;
    }
    private static string SubMenus(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<menu> SubMenu, int Catid)
    {
        string htmlOutput = string.Empty;
        var subMenu = from sm in SubMenu where sm.Depid ==Catid orderby sm.cats select sm;
        if (subMenu.Count() > 0)
        {
            htmlOutput += "<ul>";
            foreach (menu m in subMenu)
            {
                htmlOutput += "<li>";
                htmlOutput += LinkExtensions.ActionLink(html, m.Depname, null);
                htmlOutput += SubMenus(html, SubMenu, m.Catid);
                htmlOutput += "</li>";
            }
            htmlOutput += "</ul>";
        }
        return htmlOutput;}}}}
```

my Controller is :

```
public class FrontController : Controller
{
   // MenuEntities MEnt = new MenuEntities();
    NewDatabaseEntities Db = new NewDatabaseEntities();
   // menu MEnt  = new menu();
   // [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Menu()
    {
        var mMenu = Db.Dep_Table.ToList();
        return PartialView(mMenu)
    }
}
```

In partial view I want to call htmlhelper mthod "ParentMenus" using @Html.Raw.I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. I recommend changing your HTML Helper to return an `HtmlString` that contains the HTML. Then you can avoid using `@Html.Raw()`, which is almost always a bad practice (though it has its purposes).
2. In your Razor view page (the CSHTML file), put `@using DBMvc.Htmlhlpr` at the top of the file to ensure the helper namespace has been imported. Then to call the helper use `@Html.ParentMenus(...)`.

Item #1 isn't strictly necessary, but it's what all the built-in HTML helpers do and is generally a good practice.

If that's not it, please indicate what error you're getting (if any).

Comment: If I use HtmlString instead of HtmlHelper then in view what I do if not use Html.Raw??

Comment: Just use your helper directly: `@Html.ParentMenus(...)`

Answer (score 2):

### Way 1:

Include the namespace in your view where you need to call:

```
@using DBMvc.Htmlhlpr
```

and then use it:

```
@Html.ParentMenus() // pass the parameters which are needed in this IEnumarable<T>
```

### Way 2:

In general, we don't want to include namespace on every view where we want to  use helper, so we can add namespace in Views **web.config** under `<namespaces>` and then we don't need to include namespace in every view:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor> 
   <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> 
   <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"> 
     <namespaces> 
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" /> 
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" /> 
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" /> 
       <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" /> 
       <add namespace="DBMvc.Htmlhlpr" /> 
     </namespaces> 
   </pages> 
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

and in view:

```
@Html.ParentMenus()
```

Here is a  [**article**](http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/) explaining [How to create custom HTML Helpers for ASP.NET MVC and Razor View Engine](http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/) and here is official asp.net mvc article [Creating Custom Html Helpers C#](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Comment: The syntax in the first code block is incorrect. You need to use `@using SomeNamespace` as I show in my answer.

Comment: @Eilon there are two ways one is ``@{
using DBMvc.Htmlhlpr;
}`` or ``@using DBMvc.Htmlhlpr;``

Comment: I don't believe that does the same thing. I believe that's just a `using` statement for an `IDisposable`.

Comment: The only way to import a namespace within a Razor file is with `@using` - I just tried it.

Comment: No semicolon when doing `@using Foo.Bar` either :)

Comment: I added namespace in Web.config.

Comment: in view I tried @Html.ParentMenus(Model) but getting error in controller method.I guess I m doing mistake in model class and dun know how to correct that..!!

Comment: debug you helper and see where it's breaking

Comment: @EhsanSajjad well I would definitely mark it as answere if it solved my problem.